# Scheduled Task Run whether user is logged on or not. What does it mean?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I have tried researching this, but have been unsuccessful finding an answer. I want to set up a scheduled task as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. I would like to know exactly what "Run whether the user is logged on or not" means. Does it mean that it will run whether the current user is logged on or not or does it mean that it will run whether "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" (or whatever is defined for "Run as" in the task) is logged on or not?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the "Run whether the user is logged on or not" means that the process will run at session 0 where it will not have a UI. You should use this for tasks that don't require user interaction.

If you want to run whether a user is logged on or not you should use the appropriate trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize - I have finally found the answer: "You can specify that a task should run even if the account under which the task is scheduled to run is not logged on when the task is triggered. To do this, select the radio button labeled Run whether user is logged on or not." Looks like I need to select run whether user is logged on or not since it is using NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.

Comment: That setting is probably redundant for the SYSTEM account.